# loopback.io get related result error thrown

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a `hasOne` relation between two models (`server` and `pool`) and I'm periodically updating the child via a cron.

```
Server.findOne({
    where:{
        id: 1
    }
}, function(err, server) {
    if (err || !server) return next("Server not found");
    if (!_.isArray(pool)) return next("Invalid pool");

    server.pool(function(err, ip_pool){
        if(err) return next(err);

        if(ip_pool) {
            server.pool.destroy();
        }

        server.pool.create({
            pool: pool
        }, function(err) {
            next(err);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that I get an error each time a new `pool` comes in stating: `TypeError: Object #<ModelConstructor> has no method 'pool'` which hits right on this line: `server.pool(function(err, ip_pool){`.

I followed the docs but I can't seem to find out why this error is thrown.

Comment: (a) Can you point at the docs or reference material that you mimiced for this line: `server.pool(function(err, ip_pool){` and (b) if you haven't yet then go ahead and try out `server.pool.findOne()` or `server.pool.find()` just for trial and error instead. (c) spend some time looking into `loopback-console` module as it will let you quickly debug syntax errors and try out new things: https://github.com/GovRight/loopback-console